# When will the "jar" command refuse to add a class to a .jar file?

Tags: java, class, jar, scons

I have 204 total classes (most of the classes are inner classes).  For months, I have been building fine with SCons (SCons just calls the jar command).

For some reason, it stopped adding the last inner class for a particular class.  For example, suppose I have the following classes:

```
class1
class2
class3
class4
class5
class6
...
class79
class80
```

Before this last change, SCons would jar everything fine.  But NOW... it specifically does not add class80 to it's jar command. (I see an omission of the class80 in the jar command).

Is there an instance where the jar command just ignores certain classes?

----------- EDIT.  I found the culprit.  For some reason this inner class is not recognized my SCons!

```
vehicleFilter = new RowFilter<Object, Object>(){ 
public boolean include(Entry<? extends Object, ? extends Object> entry)                {                                                 
    {return false;}  
};
```

Comment: I have seeemed to have isolated the problem, but unsure why it breaks under SCons/jar.  I am working with JTables and adding a RowFilter... for some reason it's not accepting the row filter inner class? But this still does not solve my problem

Comment: Is that the only anonymous type that's ignored, or is it the only anonymous type that you have, period?

Comment: Hi Tim.  Of the 204 classes, about half are anonymous classes (class, class$1, class$2 ... etc).  I have a mixture of local classes also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than pass a whole list of class files to the Jar command, you can pass a directory. This avoids problems with SCons's java parser as SCons will scan the directory for files and jar up anything it finds.

Something like the following will compile files in "src" to the directory "classes", then create a jar from the contents of "classes":

```
env = Environment(tools=['javac', 'jar'])
env.Java(target='classes', source='src')
env.Jar(target='foo.jar', source=['classes', 'Manifest.txt'],
        JARCHDIR='$SOURCE')
```

The manifest file "Manifest.txt" is in the root of your project here. The only requirement is that it begins with the text "Manifest-Version".

Comment: Things get complicated if I had a Manifest.txt file in the mix.  If I have this Manifest, and I want it to be the root level directory of my project (the dir before src/ and classes/), how would I accomplish this? SCons skips it if we let JARCHDIR to classes/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `JAVAVERSION='1.6'` as an argument to your `env.Java()` call:

```
env.Java(target='classes', source='src', JAVAVERSION='1.6')
```

Without this, if you're compiling with a current `javac`, SCons won't determine the correct names for anonymous inner classes, so when those bad class file names get passed to `jar`, it will fail.

Comment: In `jar`ing class files(in my use case), SCons doesn't seem to be picking all the class files for a class with inner classes(not anonymous inner classes, btw). Adding `JAVAVERSION` didn't seem to solve the problem for me. Any thoughts on what I should be doing?

Answer (score 0):

SCons may construct a command line by listing all classes to jar on it and that may get too long (either a platform limitation or a heuristic inside SCons).

You need to peek inside the SCons package to see what goes on.

Any particular reason you don't just use ant?

Comment: Yes ... my project is mostly all C++ with this exception. I personally don't think it's the limit is too long (although 204 is pretty big).  I've narrowed it down to the RowFilter Class. See My edited q