# SCons not picking up all class files when creating a jar

Tags: java, jar, scons

SCons neophyte here. I am using it(version 2.0) to create a jar as follows:

```
compiled_classes = env.Java \
                   (target = compiled_classes_dir, 
                    source = source_tld, 
                    JAVAVERSION='1.6',
                    JAVACLASSPATH=['source_tld/libs/' + 
                                   file.name 
                                   for file in 
                                   Glob('source_tld/' +
                                   'libs/*.jar')])

new_jar = env.Jar(target = jar_name,
                  source = compiled_classes_dir)
```

I am seeing an issue wherein class files belonging to classes that have inner classes(which when compiled into class files have a `$` in the name) are not being handled properly i.e. they do not get included in the generated JAR. Any suggestions to address this would be greatly appreciated. TIA.

PS: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5909910/391113) suggestion to add `JAVAVERSION` didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Since SCons is incorrectly calculating the output classes I would suggest this workaround.

```
compiled_classes = env.Java \
                   (target = compiled_classes_dir, 
                    source = source_tld, 
                    JAVAVERSION='1.6',
                    JAVACLASSPATH=['source_tld/libs/' + 
                                   file.name 
                                   for file in 
                                   Glob('source_tld/' +
                                   'libs/*.jar')])
#workaround to make sure classes are cleaned
env.Clean(compiled_classes, env.Dir(compiled_classes_dir))

# its important to set the JARCHDIR or the Jar command will not be run
# from the correct location if you want an executable Jar add the manifest here  
new_jar = env.Jar(target = jar_name,
                  source = [compiled_classes_dir], JARCHDIR='$SOURCE')
```